# Common Session for Windows Store Application

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Our Team is trying to build multiple Windows 8 Store Apps for an enterprise.

How do we maintain a common session for all apps(where we store data which need to be shared)?
How do we enable direct interaction between the apps developed i.e. sharing objects or string(JSON) among the apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not built in way to do this. Realistically you probably have three options to share data between applications.

- The first is to use the cloud / web services. This makes the most sense as you'd have full control about what is shared, authentication etc. Using libraries such as [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) could let you add real time functionality between the applications as well as multiple users.
- The Share contract, by using custom data formats you could enable the apps to share specialised data between each of them. This can make sense if the user has a set of data they want to send to another application to enable a quick piece of workflow as the Share target is only partially launched. This also is limited in that it's enabled by user action.
- Custom protocol handlers, by giving each app it's only protocol *my-custom-app:///some-action?param1=value* etc then you can pass data between apps, note this launches the app in question when you launch that uri. This would be best for more longer running scenarios.

I'd suggest a combination of all three depending on the user action. Cloud services to store the data for the user and then a mixture of Share and Protocol to enable to the user to smartly move the apps seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Here exactly the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160836/share-data-among-multiple-users-of-a-winrt-app/21162010#21162010) as yours. In short: there is no such ability.  Sometimes I think that it will be easier to share data via Internet that in device.